# javascript: regex must contain a string, but it also not contain a certain string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to have a regex which must contain a string and not contain another string.

For example: 
The urls are:

`/news/create`,

`/news/5a40778e82264f0d689fc345`

`/news/5a40824382264f0d689fc347`

`/news/list`

`/files`

`/files/43er778e82264fref32fcre4`

**I want to get only:**

`/news/5a40778e82264f0d689fc345`

and

`/news/5a40824382264f0d689fc347`

It means that the url must contains `/news`, but **it should not** `/news/create` or `/news/list`. Just need news detail like `/news/:id`.
Other urls like: `/files/xxx` **should not** return as well.

How can I get the regex obtain like that?

Thank in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A regex to match an alpha numeric string isn't hard to find...

Comment: what are the rules of what you get ? Is the id as a fixed length ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/\/news\/(?!create|list).*/
```

Comment: @Andreas: jack.pop is asking the url must contains /news, but it should not /news/create or /news/list... I meet the specs.

Comment: Yes, but he's only interested in one special case of url: `/news/:id` (_"Just need news detail like `/news/:id`"_), hence it would be easier to only accept those instead of adding exceptions for everything else.

Comment: Thank @PierreFrançois. This approach is the best so far. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regex

```
/^\/news\/[^a-zA-z]/g
```

```js
var arr = ['/news/create','/news/5a40778e82264f0d689fc345','/news/5a40824382264f0d689fc347','/news/list','/files','/files/43er778e82264fref32fcre4'];

var result = arr.reduce((r, url) => {
  if(/^\/news\/[^a-zA-z]/g.test(url))
    r.push(url);
  return r;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That only work if the `id` start by numeric, not an alphabet.
I want to return urls which has preceded `/news/` and not follow by `create` or `list`

Answer (score 0):

An approach could be to use a positive lookahead to check if there is at least one digit and at least one lowercase character after `/news` a regex like:

[`^\/news\/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-z\d]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/Yf8gjF/2/)

**Explanation**

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Match `/news/`
- A positive lookahead which asserts at least one lowercase character `(?=.*[a-z])`
- A positive lookahead which asserts at least one digit `(?=.*\d)`
- Match a lowercase character or a digit one or more times `[a-z\d]+`
- The end of the string `$`

If you want to find that pattern in a string, you could end with a word boundary `\b` like:

[`\/news\/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-z\d]+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/Yf8gjF/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Partly summarizing the earlier answers; this problem cannot be directly solved without accepting some extra specs about the difference between IDs and other URL segments. The answer depends on what extra specs you'd want to accept:

- IDs have a given length of 24 characters: `/^\/news\/[a-z0-9]{24}$/i`
- IDs have more than, say, 20 characters: `/^\/news\/[a-z0-9]{20,}$/i`
- You have a blacklist of other URLs, e.g. `create` and `list`: `/^\/news\/(?!create|list)/i`
- The other URLs, like `/news/create` will never contain any digits: `/^\/news\/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-z\d]+$/i`
- (A combination of the above, say, IDs contain more than 20 characters and at least 1 digit: `/^\/news\/(?=.*\d)[a-z0-9]{20,}$/i`)
- etc..